# Strict convexity of penalized regression function

Tags: statistics, regression

I have a quick question about a comment that R. Tibshirani makes in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0313.pdf) paper right at the beginning. He says that the LASSO solution is unique when $\text{rank}(X)=p$ by strict convexity of the criterion. I just want to confirm if my understanding as to why the criterion is strictly convex is correct.

This amounts to showing that $f(\vec{\beta})=\frac{1}{2}||\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}||_2^2+\lambda||\vec{\beta}||_1$ is a strictly convex function when $\text{rank}(X)=p$. First, we know that $|| \cdot ||_2^2$ is a strictly convex function and that $|| \cdot ||_1$ is a convex function. Thus for $\theta \in (0,1)$ and $x \neq y$ we know that $||\theta x + (1-\theta)y||_2^2<\theta ||x||_2^2 +(1-\theta)||y||_2^2$ and $||\theta x + (1-\theta)y||_1 \leq \theta ||x||_1 +(1-\theta)||y||_1$.

So, let $\theta \in (0,1)$ with $\vec{\beta}_1 \neq \vec{\beta}_2$. Then we have

\begin{align}
f\left(\theta\vec{\beta}_1+(1-\theta)\vec{\beta_2}\right) & = \frac{1}{2}||\vec{y}-X(\theta\vec{\beta}_1+(1-\theta)\vec{\beta}_2)||_2^2+\lambda||\theta\vec{\beta}_1+(1-\theta)\vec{\beta}_2||_1\\
& = \frac{1}{2}||\theta(\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_1)+(1-\theta)(\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_2)||_2^2+\lambda||\theta\vec{\beta}_1+(1-\theta)\vec{\beta}_2||_1.
\end{align}

Now since $\text{rank}(X)=p$ ($X$ is full column rank) we know that that if $\vec{\beta}_1 \neq \vec{\beta}_2$ then it must be the case that $X\vec{\beta}_1 \neq X\vec{\beta}_2$. Thus $\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_1 \neq \vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_2$. By the strict convexity of the squared euclidean norm we can thus conclude that

$$
||\theta(\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_1)+(1-\theta)(\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_2)||_2^2<\theta||\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_1||_2^2+(1-\theta)||\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_2||_2^2.
$$

So continuing from above, and using convexity of $|| \cdot ||_1$ we have that

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}||\theta(\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_1)+(1-\theta)(\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_2)||_2^2+\lambda||\theta\vec{\beta}_1+(1-\theta)\vec{\beta}_2||_1 & <\frac{1}{2}(\theta||\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_1||_2^2+(1-\theta)||\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_2||_2^2)+\lambda(\theta||\vec{\beta}_1||_1+(1-\theta)||\vec{\beta}_2||_1)\\
& = \theta(\frac{1}{2}||\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_1||_2^2+\lambda||\vec{\beta}_1||_1)+(1-\theta)(\frac{1}{2}||\vec{y}-X\vec{\beta}_2||_2^2+\lambda||\vec{\beta}_2||_1)\\
& = \theta f(\vec{\beta}_1)+(1-\theta)f(\vec{\beta}_2)
\end{align}

and we have strict convexity.

Comment: Yes, the square norm is strongly convex which implies strict convexity. You only have to worry about the injectivity of $X$ then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lasso, we have $f(w)=g(w)+h(w)$ where $g(w)$ is the squared error and is strictly convex when columns of $X$ are independent ($rank(X)=p$). $h(w)$ is L1 norm and hence, convex. You can show that sum of a strictly convex function and a convex function is strictly convex.
**Proof:**
\begin{equation}\label{g}
g(\alpha w_1 + (1-\alpha)w_2) < \alpha g(w_1) + (1-\alpha)g(w_2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{h}
h(\alpha w_1 + (1-\alpha)w_2) \leq \alpha h(w_1) + (1-\alpha)h(w_2)
\end{equation}
Add the above two eqns to get,
\begin{equation}\label{f}
f(\alpha w_1 + (1-\alpha)w_2) < \alpha f(w_1) + (1-\alpha)f(w_2)
\end{equation}
If you want to show strict convexity of $g(w)$, use Hessian of $g(w)=X^TX$ is positive definite when $rank(X)=p$. The proof you have is also correct.

Comment: Yes, my issue was confirming why the columns o $X$ being independent implies strict convexity. I think my proof is correct and just wanted to confirm.